# Prefetch related django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm developping an application written in Django and I have some problems to do a correct request using select_related and prefetch_related

I have three models :

```
class Intervention(BaseModel):
    date = DateField()
    housing = ForeignKey('contract.Housing', related_name='interventions')

class Housing(BaseModel):
    address = CharField(max_length=CHAR_FIELD_LENGTH) 

class Tenant(BaseModel):
    name = CharField(max_length=CHAR_FIELD_LENGTH)
    phone = CharField(max_length=CHAR_FIELD_LENGTH, blank=True, null=True)
    housing = ForeignKey(Housing, related_name='tenants')
```

I am requesting on the model Interventions, if I want to have access to the housing informations, I just have to use select_related :

```
Interventions.object.select_related("housing").filter(...)
```

But I don't know how to access to the tenants using prefetch_related :

```
Interventions.object.select_related("housing").prefetch_related("housing__tenants")
```

doesn't seems to work, because it makes a query everytime I try to access to the tenants list.
Is there a way to access to the tenant list, and best, to do a filter on I (like first Tenant found which has no name).

Thanks for you answers.

Algelos

***Edit : Here is some code : ***

I'm requesting like I said :

```
interventionPreventivesVisits = InterventionPreventiveVisit.objects.select_related("housing").prefetch_related("housing__tenants").filter(date__range=(self.weekDays[0], self.weekDays[len(self.weekDays)-1]))
```

self.weekDays is a table of days, to display the interventions in a calendar.

And then, I want to display the tenant which has no name :

In my template, I loop through the interventions :

```
{%for inter in interventions %}
    {%if day == inter.date %}
        {{ inter | get_schedule_html_formated | safe}}
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

And I have a templateTag to display the HTML :

```
def get_schedule_html_formated(intervention):
    housingTenant = None
    for tenant in intervention.housing.tenants.all(): # Here it does a query
        if tenant.name is not None:
            housingTenant = tenant
    ....
```

and then I write and return my html

I'm searching a way to set housingTenant without doing a new query.

Is that better :) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields
>   of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason,
>   select_related gets the related objects in the same database query.
>   However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from
>   joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to
>   single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a **separate lookup for each
>   relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python**.

update for comment:

it is better to place filter first here (order in django can affect on results):

```
interventionPreventivesVisits = InterventionPreventiveVisit.objects.filter(
    date__range=(self.weekDays[0], self.weekDays[len(self.weekDays)-1])
).select_related("housing"
).prefetch_related("housing__tenants")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried without the 's' on tenant but it causes an error : `'housing__tenant' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`, which seems logic because my related name is tenants. About PREfetch, it's just a mistake while writing my question, I will edit that :). And so, with you final quote in bold, you're saying that I can't access to my tenants without doing one more request. Is my interpretation correct ?

Comment: @alglos you right about tenants, but now it should work.. Correct i think, one extra query for prefetch and you can acces to tenants without additional queries

Comment: @npdu, Ok, thanks for you answer. So my query will automatically be dependant on my number of interventions if I loop on my interventions to get the tenant :/ Do I have any way to avoid that ? (like I said, I only want the first tenant found which has no name, so maybe with custom_values, or something ? I'm really newbie for this kind of requests ^^)

Comment: I add it under my Edit

Comment: @algelos changing order didnt help? (my advise to not using all() was wrong)

Comment: @ndpu, please, fix `prefetct_related` -> `prefetch_related` (last line). I can't submit edit, because its 1 symbol.

Comment: @ ndpu, thanks a lot, place prefetch_related in the last position (or at less behind the filter) works great ! I still don't understand why (in that case it doesn't seems to affect the query...), but I know what to do know :). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
interventionPreventivesVisits = InterventionPreventiveVisit.objects.\
    prefetch_related("housing__tenants").\
    filter(date__range=(self.weekDays[0], self.weekDays[len(self.weekDays)-1]))
```